# Django TypeError at /sitemap.xml sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'

Tags: python, django

I have weird problem with my sitemap page.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import datetime
import urllib

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from pytz import UTC

from mychat.models import Question

MONTHLY = 'monthly'
WEEKLY = 'weekly'
DAILY = 'daily'
HOURLY = 'hourly'
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=UTC)

# The following lists are separated only for fixed ordering.


class RecentForumViewPaginationSitemap(Sitemap):
    """
    Sitemap generator that takes Django Recent tab in forum list view and
    generates all pages in pagination.
    """
    changefreq = DAILY
    priority = 0.90
    protocol = 'https'

    def items(self):
        post_queryset = Question.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        paginator = Paginator(post_queryset, 12)
        return paginator.page_range

    def location(self, page):
        return '?'.join([reverse('question_list'), urllib.urlencode({'recent_page': page})])

sitemaps = {
    'recent_forum_views': RecentForumViewPaginationSitemap,
}
```

It appread after recent upgrade to Django 1.9.7

urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from my.sitemap import sitemaps

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps,
                                                                     'template_name': 'my/custom_sitemap.xml'}),
)
```

custom_sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
{% spaceless %}
{% for url in urlset %}
<url>
<loc>{{ url.location }}</loc>
{% if url.lastmod %}<lastmod>{{ url.lastmod|date:"Y-m-d" }}</lastmod>{% endif %}
{% if url.changefreq %}<changefreq>{{ url.changefreq }}</changefreq>{% endif %}
{% if url.priority %}<priority>{{ url.priority }}</priority>{% endif %}
</url>
{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
</urlset>
```

I am getting traceback:

```
ERROR base.handle_uncaught_exception.284 Internal Server Error: /sitemap.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bartosz/.virtualenvs/my9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/bartosz/.virtualenvs/my9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bartosz/.virtualenvs/my9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py", line 16, in inner
    response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bartosz/.virtualenvs/my9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py", line 67, in sitemap
    protocol=req_protocol))
  File "/home/bartosz/.virtualenvs/my9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py", line 104, in get_urls
    urls = self._urls(page, protocol, domain)
  File "/home/bartosz/.virtualenvs/my9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py", line 112, in _urls
    for item in self.paginator.page(page).object_list:
  File "/home/bartosz/.virtualenvs/my9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 55, in page
    return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
```

I wonder if someone encountered similar problem recently or can point me in right direction to solve it. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your backwards-incompatible change:

- [Make paginator.page_range an iterator](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23190)

To resolve this return the list from the `items()` method:

```
def items(self):
    post_queryset = Question.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    paginator = Paginator(post_queryset, 12)
    return list(paginator.page_range)
```

Note: I am far from being an expert in Django and the Sitemap framework - there could be a better way to solve this. I hope this would, at least, be a step into the right direction.